# Counting measure is sigma-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have to solve the following problem

Let $B=\{b_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable set of real numbers (and no other specifications, $B$ could be  $\mathbb{N}$). Consider the counting measure

$\mu(A)=|A\cap B|=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 1_A(b_n),$ $A \in \mathbb{B}$.

Show that $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure over $(\Re,\mathbb{B})$

I've already shown that $\mu$ is a measure, so I only need to prove $\sigma$-additivity, i.e. there exist $A_n\in\mathbb{B}$ such that $\cup A_n=\Re$, and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$. Any pointers as to how these sets can be selected? I was thinking $(a,a+1), a\in \mathbb{N}$, but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Is your $R$ the Real numbers? If so, try \mathbb R.

Comment: Actually, your idea works, because the measure of each of your sets is finite , i.e., under $\mu$, and it is a countable collection.

Comment: Try $A_n=\{b_n\}$ (and fill things out with one other set).

Answer (score 3):

Can you show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite over $B$? If so, how should you extend the cover to deal with the rest of the space $\mathbb{R} \backslash B$?