# A $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

I was working on the following question from *Measure Theory* by Cohn, Exercise 1.2.2:

> Define $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by letting $\mu(A)$ be the number of rational numbers in $A$ (of course $\mu(A) = +\infty$ is there are infinitely many rational numbers in $A$). Show that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite measure under which each open subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure.

I considered looking at the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't see how I should proceed from there. I tried comparing to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612332/counting-measure-is-sigma-finite-measure), but as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense unlike $\mathbb{N}$ I again ran into problems.

Comment: There are 2 questions in your exercise. Which one are you asking help for? And what did you *write* (not only looked at) to begin your attempt(s)? Please do not just ask. Include some work. The first step is to write down the definitions of the notions involved in the question. Considering "the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$" is a good idea. What does it mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that a measure space is $\sigma$-finite, you need to find an increasing sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that each $A_n$ has finite $\mu$-measure and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n=\mathbb R$.

Since the irrational numbers have $\mu$-measure $0$, i.e. $\mu(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)=0$, you can start constructing a sequence by setting $A_0=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. You'll notice that if you set $A_1=A_0\cup \{q_1\}$ for some $q_1\in\mathbb Q$, then $\mu(A_1)=1<\infty$. Similarly, for another $q_2\in\mathbb Q$ and $A_2=A_1\cup \{q_2\}$ you get $\mu(A_2)=2<\infty$.

Now you simply have to think about whether it is possible to iterate this procedure and cover all of $\mathbb Q$ with such $A_n$.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb R=\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Q} \{x\}\cup Q^{c}$ so $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite.

Every non-empty open set contains infinitely many rational numbers.